# How can I permanently add a class path to my Mac terminal?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, classpath

I want to set my path permanently for the following directory:

```
/Users/syalam/Library/android-sdk-mac_86/platform-tools
```

Not sure how to do it from the terminal. I tried:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/syalam/Library/android-sdk-mac_86/platform-tools
```

but it only works temporarily. After I close my shell it no longer exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this entry to your `CLASSPATH` environment variable in your `.bashrc`:

```
export CLASSPATH="/Users/syalam/Library/android-sdk-mac_86/platform-tools:$CLASSPATH"
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the difference between setting PATH and CLASSPATH?

Comment: `PATH` is the list of directories in which you shell will search for commands, in the order where they appear -- ie, if you type `ls`, the shell will search for `/bin/ls`, then `/usr/bin/ls` if `PATH` is `/bin:/usr/bin`. `CLASSPATH` is a list of directories where the JVM will look for classes.

Comment: Uhm, I know it's been long, but... Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

http://blog.just2us.com/2011/05/setting-path-variable-in-mac-permanently/

**Set permanently for a user:**

Edit the user’s bash profile (replace USERNAME)

```
pico ~USERNAME/.bash_profile
```

Insert (or edit) this line

```
PATH=$PATH:/my/new/path/
```

Press ctrl-x, then ctrl-y, to save the file.

Done.

**Set for all users**

```
sudo pico /etc/paths
```

Enter your superuser password to edit, and insert or edit this link

```
PATH=$PATH:/my/new/path/
```

That’s it! Enjoy your path!

Comment: After many hours of going over quite a few answers here on stack overflow (and elsewhere), this was the only solution that ended up working on my mbp retina (2013), running mac OS 10.11.6. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I tried different things, I could only set temporarily. Atlast tried this and got worked

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/User/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools:/User/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

this will set the path permanently.

> **/User/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk** 
>   this is my Android SDK path

Answer (score 0):

Set `classpath` in your `bashprofile` and close the terminal and restart
it will work sure

Do the following:

1- vi .bash_profile  {open in terminal} home directory
 2- add this line export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/{//directory//}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash, add:

```bash
export CLASSPATH="/path/to/folder:${CLASSPATH}"
```

to your `~/.bashrc` file. If you are in zsh, add it to your `~/.zshrc` file.  This variable will then be available in each new terminal session.