# antlr4-Can't load Hello as lexer or parser

Tags: antlr4

I recently have to use parser to do a project. I download `ANTLR4` and follow the steps described in the book `The Definitive ANTLR4 Reference`. The following are the steps I type in command line:

```
 1. export CLASSPATH=".:/<Mydirectory>/antlr-4.2.2-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH"
 2. alias antlr4='java -jar /<My directory>/antlr-4.2.2-complete.jar'
 3. alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig'
 4. antlr4 Hello.g4
```

All the things work fine, it generates java files that I need. However, after I enter

```
 5. grun Hello r -tokens
```

It reports

> Can't load Hello as lexer or parser.

I google some info, but still cannot figure out what happened.

Comment: oh, I solved that problem by using javac -g .*java in that directory

Comment: I got the same problem, I solved it by adding `.` to classpath. (I already compiled java files)

Comment: Note that the CLASSPATH separator is a semi-colon (';') now. At least on Windows.

Answer (score 52):

You generated Java source files by running ANTLR on the grammar, but TestRig is looking for compiled **.class** files. You need to run the Java compiler on the source files before using TestRig.

Comment: You mean I have to compile java source code like HelloBaseListener.java, HelloLexer.java and HelloParser.java? I use command "java *.java" to compile all the java files, but it reports "Could not find or load main class HelloBaseListener.java"

Comment: @user3162707 You need "javac *.java", not "java *.java".  javac is the java compiler, which takes java files and compiles them to class files.

Comment: I forgot to add `.` i.e. the current directory, where my `.class` files are, in the class path while invoking the `TestRig`.

Answer (score 40):

I had exactly the same error on Windows. My batch is set like this at first:

`java -cp "C:\ANTLR\antlr-4.4-complete.jar" org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig %*`

It turns out all my compiled `Hello*.class` files are located in current folder and I forget to include the `current folder` in the `-cp`. After I change to below. It works. **Note the leading dot in the `-cp`**.

`java -cp ".;C:\ANTLR\antlr-4.4-complete.jar" org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig %*`

Comment: This has been the solution for me - including the leading dot and semicolon to the CLASSPATH variable. Thanks!

Comment: saved my day. My CLASSPATH looks like  
.;C:\Programs\ANTLRv4\antlr-4.7-complete.jar  
and my grun bat file looks like  
java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig %*

Comment: this was it for me too it was the dot.

Answer (score 4):

After all of your `*.java` files have been generated, and your `*.class` files have been generated, and your `%CLASSPATH%` is set correctly, based on the "Hello World" example grammar, you should not see this error.

If you don't have the "antlr-runtime-4.4.jar" in your `%CLASSPATH%` environment variable and run "grun" code from the book, you will receive this error when you run your generated parser based on the grammar you supplied.

`%CLASSPATH%` should be:

```
C:\libraries\antlr-4.4-complete.jar;C:\libraries\antlr-runtime-4.4.jar;
```

Enter the input after this command is entered.  Like "hello parrt" in the book example.  Then enter `CTRL+Z` (in Windows) to end the input, or `CTRL+D` (on Unix).

Answer (score 4):

On macOS, the correct incantations appear to be (assuming you've [downloaded ANTLR 4.8](https://www.antlr.org/download.html), and created a file [Hello.g4](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/2ba38605b949a3208230d2c63d2896e035c36723/doc/getting-started.md#a-first-example)):

```
java -jar antlr-4.8-complete.jar Hello.g4
javac -cp antlr-4.8-complete.jar Hello*.java
java --class-path ".:antlr-4.8-complete.jar" org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig Hello r -gui
```

These commands will generate the Java source files, compile them, and then start TestRig, waiting for you to enter an expression.

Answer (score 3):

In order to do this correctly, I'm going to assume that you've got a JDK installed and added to your system PATH variable.

In this case you will need two batch files to help you out.

`antlr4.bat`: `java -cp antlr-4.2-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.Tool %*`

`grun.bat`: `java -cp .;antlr-4.2-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig %*`

This also assumes that you have the `antlr-4.2-complete.jar` in the current directory.  Beyond that simply follow the instructions in the [getting started guide](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Getting+Started+with+ANTLR+v4).

Note that I used the `-cp` flag because, on Windows 7, I'm not seeing a `CLASSPATH` variable.

Answer (score 2):

You need Antlr jar file and the .bat files in your `CLASSPATH`. I know because I had the exact same problem.

### **Windows**

Go to the start menu and search for `Environment Variables` and you will find `Set Environment Variables for Users` or something like that. There should be a section labeled `Variables for all Users`. If you see `%CLASSPATH%`, click it, then click the `edit` button under that box. Go to the very end of the list and add `C:\**PATH TO JAR FILE**\antlr-X.X-complete.jar;` to the end. Repeat that with the path to each of the .bat files. If you don't see `%CLASSPATH%`, then under the box, click the button that says add, and add `%CLASSPATH%`, and do the same process.

### **OSX**

I am not as familiar with OSX and the storage system, but you can do `export CLASSPATH="/Users/**USER**/**PATH TO JAR FILE**/antlr-X.X-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH"` in the terminal. Repeat, but with the paths to each of the .bat files. Simple as that hopefully. Let me know if this is wrong, because like I said above, OSX is not my strong point. You could also check out this question on StackOverflow: [How can I permanently add a class path to my Mac terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629948/how-can-i-permanently-add-a-class-path-to-my-mac-terminal)

***I added OSX instructions just in case anyone else had this problem, but on OSX! :)***

***ALSO: Replace the X's in `antlr-X.X-complete.jar` with the version number, or just make it the name of the jar file. Whatever floats your boat.***

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS users using homebrew with antlr4.

`brew install antlr`

Two things:

- When using brew, the Antlr jar DOES NOT install in the typical location you see everywhere else. It installs here: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/antlr/4.10.1/antlr-4.10.1-complete.jar`
- In Java, you can optionally pass in different classes during compilation. `javac` looks at `$CLASSPATH` to find any additional java classes it should look for when compiling a program.

If `javac *.java` is failing after generating a grammer with `antlr Hello.g4`. Make sure your classpath is set correctly so the generated java code can look for the other code in $CLASSPATH to compile correctly

`export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/antlr/4.10.1/antlr-4.10.1-complete.jar"`

NOTE: Newer versions of javac don't require the "." in front of CLASSPATH.