# ANTLR Warning: TestRig moved to org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig

Tags: java, shell, batch-file, cygwin, antlr

I have been trying to get ANTLR to work all day. I have used several websites including antlr.org, numerous StackOverflow queries and the textbook by Terence Parr. I am on a Windows 7 machine (work machine, can't change to Linux) but I have tried this on both CommandPrompt and Cygwin, with the same result.

No matter what I do, when it comes time to use the grun file, I always come up with the same error in the end:

> Warning: TestRig moved to org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig; calling automatically
>   Can't load Hello as lexer or parser

I have the most recent versions of the JRE and JDK on my computer, as well as the most recent version of cygwin.

I can run the batch files for grun and antlr4 from anywhere, so I'm strongly guessing my path is set correctly. I can run antlr4.bat with absolutely no issue. It creates every file the text book says I should see:

`Hello.g4      HelloBaseListener.java  HelloLexer.tokens   HelloParser.java        Hello.tokens  HelloLexer.java         HelloListener.java`

I can run javac on those files and it generates various CLASS files:

`HelloBaseListener.class   HelloLexer.class   HelloListener.class   HelloParser$RContext.class   HelloParser.class`

But then, when I try to run grun on it, I get this:

> Warning: TestRig moved to org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig; calling automatically
>   Can't load Hello as lexer or parser

I've tried several combinations of commands to use the grun file, but the one it says to use in the book is:

```
grun.bat Hello r -tree
```

I've also changed the .bat file with grun several times, just to experiment, using different combinations in the books and on the sites, but I always come back to this:

```
java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig %*
```

That is what my boss told me to use, and it works for him.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/147

Comment: No. It made no difference. Thank you, though.

Comment: I have the same problem on OS X 10.9.5 and brew install.
added:
export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/Cellar/antlr/4.5.1/antlr-4.5.1-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH"

after:
grun Hello r -tokens
Warning: TestRig moved to org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig; calling automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in your `grun.bat` command

```
java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig %*
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, there is actually already a thread with the solution here --> [antlr4-Can't load Hello as lexer or parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315302/antlr4-cant-load-hello-as-lexer-or-parser) 
The first part of the message "Warning: TestRig moved to org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig; calling automatically" just means that the TestRig order is saved to another location, it works anyway but I changed my batch data accordingly and did not get the Warning anymore. The second part of the message is the actual problem (see link). In my case I forgot the "." (dot) in my CLASSPATH in Windows.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could paste the answer into your answer - external links are unreliable as could be lost in the future and lose any value for others with the same problem.