# Putting Intel Python distribution into PATH?

Tags: python, path, anaconda, intel-mkl

So, I made the leap and uninstalled Python to install Intel's [distribution](https://software.intel.com/en-us/distribution-for-python) instead, because it conveniently includes Intel's mkl engine pre-packaged inside.

After downloading the package, you see these instructions:

[image]

Despite being straightforward, I cannot get the bottom lines to work. Essentially, I cannot get my Mac to recognize this distribution of Python as the default one. No matter how many times I have edited my `.profile` or `.bash_profile` (and I have confirmed they work, commenting the whole files makes only the system's version of python visible), `which python` keeps giving me

```
/Users/Bob/miniconda3/bin/python
```

This distribution seems to depend on anaconda, so that is probably making things hard. The current tops of both those files (to no avail) are

```
export PATH="/Users/Bob/intelpython3/bin:$PATH"
source /Users/Bob/intelpython3/bin/activate root
...
...
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After (unhyperbolically) endlessly searching and testing answers, only one worked on my 2013 macbook pro (OS 10.11.6), which was Ravi G's answer here, [How can I permanently add a class path to my Mac terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629948/how-can-i-permanently-add-a-class-path-to-my-mac-terminal)
I would love to know one day why both files need to be edited, and why virtually the rest of the internet had missed that ^^.